# ArSceneView SEGFAULT

Tags: android, react-native, arcore, sceneview

App crashes randomly after starting/resuming a "session"

Seems like this is the main error

JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)global reference table dump

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I was able to solve this segfault by switching to version 16 instead of the latest one which is not maintained any more.